# Load data from room database prior to api requests using Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I need to achieve the following logic. When application starts, load userId from shared preferences, then load user object from Room database to finally be able to make Retrofit requests using access token from the user object.

Here is what I'm currently at.

Initialize user repository with Dagger at application startup

```
class App : Application() {
    companion object {
        lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository
    }
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.factory().create(applicationContext)
        userRepository = appComponent.userRepository()
    }
}
```

Load `userId` from sharedPrefs and then load user from the db at the repository initization

```
@Singleton
class UserRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val dao: UserDao,
    private val sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences
) {
    var user: User
    private var userId: Int

    init {
        userId = sharedPrefs.getInt(PREFS_KEY_UID, 0)
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            user = dao.geUser(userId)
        }
    }
}
```

Intercept Retrofit requests to insert the token into the header

```
interface Webservice {
    companion object Factory {
        private val headerInterceptor = Interceptor() {
            val newRequest = it.request().newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ${App.userRepository.user.token}")
                .build()
            it.proceed(newRequest)
        }
        fun create(): Webservice {
            val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(headerInterceptor)
                .build();
            val retrofit = retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(client)
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .build()
            return retrofit.create(Webservice::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

The first web request is made when MainActivity's ViewModel is created

```
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: DataRepository
): ViewModel() {
    val ticket: LiveData<Data> = repository.getData(viewModelScope)
}

@Singleton
class DataRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val webservice: Webservice,
    private val dao: DataDao
) {
    fun getData(scope: CoroutineScope): LiveData<Data> {
        refreshData(scope)
        return dao.getData()
    }
    suspend fun refreshData(scope: CoroutineScope) {
        scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            ...
            val response = webservice.getData().awaitResponse()
            ...
            dao.insert(response.body()!!)
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

You might have noticed that I'm using Coroutines.

How do I make sure that `user` is loaded from the database prior to the web request is sent?

Comment: You just have to forget about the idea that the user will be loaded by the time the `Application.onCreate` method returns. You have to restructure everything around the fact that, during Android UI init, the user is not yet loaded.

Comment: What would be the best approach to get a token from a database for api requests then?

Comment: The clean way is architecting the entire app to have an async init phase during which you may show a splash screen. The UI gets populated upon receiving notice that all the backend data was brought in.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution for now. Thanks to Marko Topolnik for the comments.

Simply replace the `GlobalScope.launch` by `runBlocking` like so

```
init {
    userId = sharedPrefs.getInt(PREFS_KEY_UID, 0)
    runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
        user = dao.geUser(userId)
    }
}
```

The operation is light-weight in my case so no splash screen was needed.

Comment: `runBlocking` should be used by `main` functions and tests according to the [docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html)

Comment: are there any reasonable grounds not to use it for this particular case?

Answer (score 0):

to be sure that user was be loaded from db, you can use a `Deferred` with `async` coroutines builder and call `await` function when you access user variable. For example:

```
val user: Deferred<User>

init {

   userId = sharedPrefs.getInt(PREFS_KEY_UID, 0)
   user = GlobalScope.aync {
             dao.geUser(userId)
          }
}
```

....

```
val user = repository.user.await()
```

Comment: How would you call this in the interceptor?